# Can you show/hide the iPad Safari keyboard using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Is it possible to control the display i.e.(show/hide) of keyboard in iPad Safari through code?

I have 2 form fields;
 1. Text box (say Name)
 2. Select list/Dropdown (Say State)

My question is when user moves focus from Name to State, the keyboard is still there..Why is it so and how can I hide the keyboard when focus moves to dropdown?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question should not ask about showing the keyboard when you are only interested in hiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into a very similar problem, not sure if my solution will work for you.

In my case, I have a text input inside a form.  On submit, I'm using `e.preventDefault()` to stop the page from navigating.  I believe this was also having the effect of stopping the default action of hiding the keyboard.

To solve this, I added an explicit `input.blur()` when the form is submitted.  This seemed to be enough for safari to remove the keyboard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm having the opposite problem,i.e. the keyboard is going away when there is still a text element.  I already am using preventDefault and the keyboard is still going away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had a form were keyboard should be collapsed when type out of the field (not native behavior on ipad) and when focus select field. The only solution for me was creation of hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="blurInput" />
```

and javascript code handler for focus event:

```
$element = $(event.target);
if($element.is('select')) {
    $('#blurInput').blur();
    $element.focus();
}
```

In case you want just to blur input field another solution works perfect, but between input and select it fails

```
document.activeElement.blur();
$('input').blur();
```